# Does not support null safety, version solving failed

Tags: flutter, dart

So I tried to clone a repo on github then i ran into a problem, first of the code was all underlined with red squiggly lines, then i tried updating flutter to the latest version but still to no avail, then i tried runing flutter pub get in the terminal but it was bringing out this error

"PS C:\Users\user\Desktop\JxCodie\User> flutter pub get
Resolving dependencies... (15.0s)
The current Dart SDK version is 3.1.0.

Because tag_along depends on dependencies any which doesn't support null safety, version solving failed.

The lower bound of "sdk: '>=2.0.0 <3.0.0'" must be 2.12.0 or higher to enable null safety.
For details, see [https://dart.dev/null-safety"](https://dart.dev/null-safety%22)

Comment: try to run `flutter packages upgrade`

Comment: PS C:\Users\user\Desktop\JxCodie\User> flutter packages upgrade
Resolving dependencies... (6.7s)
The current Dart SDK version is 3.1.0.

Because tag_along depends on dependencies any which doesn't support null safety, version solving failed.

The lower bound of "sdk: '>=2.0.0 <3.0.0'" must be 2.12.0 or higher to enable null safety.
For details, see https://dart.dev/null-safety

Comment: Did you later solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

- Go to your pubspec yaml and set `sdk: '>=2.12.0 <4.0.0'` to support null safety.
- Upgrade your dependencies by doing `flutter pub upgrade --major-versions` or upgrading manually.

Comment: PS C:\Users\user\Desktop\JxCodie\User> flutter pub upgrade --major-versions
The current Dart SDK version is 3.1.0.

Because tag_along depends on dependencies any which doesn't support null safety, version solving failed.

The lower bound of "sdk: '>=2.0.0 <3.0.0'" must be 2.12.0 or higher to enable null safety.
For details, see https://dart.dev/null-safety

Comment: Did you change the lower bound of the sdk to 2.12.0?

Comment: Is tag_along a package or that is the name of the project?